# Git cloning a project asks for git@git.drupal.org password

Tags: community-official-site

I'm trying to switch to SSH keys as the password authentication is now deprecated and I am having an issue. I've created a new key pair and entered the public key in my account and setup my Git Bash to use the private key.

When I try to clone one of my projects, I get a password prompt asking for "git@git.drupal.org' password.

However, when I run  `ssh git@git.drupal.org -v`, it asks for my private key password and the output log says that I was authenticated.

> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
>   Authenticated to git.drupal.org ([140.211.10.43]:22).

Why does the above appear to authenticate but running something like the following does not?

```
git clone --branch 8.x-1.x git@git.drupal.org:project/MY_PROJECT.git
```

EDIT: I'm using Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: Is it using the right identity file? You said you created a new one.

Comment: Yes. I only have one key pair in use. Plus "ssh git@ git.drupal.org -v" says my key is found and prompts for my key password. But using the git clone command does not ask for my key password, but rather asks for git@git.drupal.org's password.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the issue by removing all git programs from my computer and then reinstalling only Git (bash). I think Tortoise Git was interfering somehow and causing the issue.

After removals and clean install, my clone worked right away. Simple.